# Расширение php не работает

Tags: php, centos, extension

Установил расширение 
https://github.com/c9s/xarray

Все как по инструкции

```
phpize
./configure
make install
```

Далее добавил в php.ini

```
extension=xarray.so
```

Перезагрузил сервер, команда php -m выдает:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xarray <----- Вот она! Якобы все хорошо!
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Далее потом уже в любом файле .php выполняю такой код:

```
echo print_r(get_loaded_extensions(),1);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
[0] => Core
[1] => date
[2] => ereg
[3] => libxml
[4] => openssl
[5] => pcre
[6] => zlib
[7] => filter
[8] => hash
[9] => pcntl
[10] => readline
[11] => Reflection
[12] => SPL
[13] => session
[14] => standard
[15] => cgi-fcgi
[16] => bcmath
[17] => bz2
[18] => calendar
[19] => ctype
[20] => curl
[21] => dom
[22] => mbstring
[23] => fileinfo
[24] => ftp
[25] => gd
[26] => gettext
[27] => gmp
[28] => iconv
[29] => intl
[30] => json
[31] => exif
[32] => mcrypt
[33] => mysql
[34] => mysqli
[35] => PDO
[36] => pdo_mysql
[37] => pdo_sqlite
[38] => Phar
[39] => posix
[40] => shmop
[41] => SimpleXML
[42] => sockets
[43] => sqlite3
[44] => sysvmsg
[45] => sysvsem
[46] => sysvshm
[47] => tidy
[48] => tokenizer
[49] => xml
[50] => wddx
[51] => xmlreader
[52] => xmlwriter
[53] => xsl
[54] => zip
[55] => mhash
[56] => Zend OPcache
)
```

И как видно xarray тут нет! И собственно при попытке использовать любую функцию из данной библиотеки пишет что неизвестная функция. Что за мистика ?

Comment: Проверьте в phpinfo, что extension вы добавили именно в тот `php.ini`, который используется вашим "любым скриптом". `php.ini` может быть много в системе.

Comment: php перезапустили?

Comment: Переустановите `php` во многих случаях это помогает